# Como faço o upload da imagem e excluo a antiga?

Tags: php, pdo

Como faço para excluir a imagem antiga e fazer o upload da nova?
O código que estou usando faz o upload, só que fica a imagem antiga e a atual na pasta...

```
$novoNome = $img;

if(isset($_POST['edit_profile_avatar']))
{
    if(!empty($_FILES['img']['name']))
    {
    // INICIO UPLOAD IMG
    //INFO IMAGEM
    $file       = $_FILES['img'];
    $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    //PASTA
    $folder     = 'upload/users/';

    //REQUISITOS
    $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
    $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 1;

    //MENSAGENS
    $msg        = array();
    $errorMsg   = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
        2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
        3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
        4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
        );

    if($numFile <= 0)
    {
        /*echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        Selecione uma imagem!
        </div>';*/
    }
    else if($numFile >=2)
    {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        Você ultrapassou o limite de upload. Selecione apenas uma foto e tente novamente!
        </div>';
    }
    else
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++)
        {
            $name   = $file['name'][$i];
            $type       = $file['type'][$i];
            $size       = $file['size'][$i];
            $error  = $file['error'][$i];
            $tmp        = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

            $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

            if($error != 0)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
            else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
            else if($size > $maxSize)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";

            else
            {

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome))
                {
                    $archive = "upload/users/" .$img;
                    unlink($archive);
                    //$msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Upload Realizado com Sucesso!";
                }
                else
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";
            }
            foreach($msg as $pop)
                echo '';
                //echo $pop.'<br>';
            }
        }
    } // input de img vazio
    else
    {
        $novoNome = $img;
    }

    try
    {
        $atualizarUsuario = $conexao->prepare("UPDATE users SET avatar=:img WHERE id=:id");
        $atualizarUsuario->bindParam(':id', $idUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $atualizarUsuario->bindParam(':img', $novoNome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $atualizarUsuario->execute();

        if($atualizarUsuario->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            echo '<script language= "JavaScript">
            location.href="/profile/'.$apelidoUsuario.'/avatar-updated";
            </script>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script language= "JavaScript">
            location.href="/profile/'.$apelidoUsuario.'/perfil-updated-error";
            </script>';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: O comando para excluir arquivos é o [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

Comment: Carrega previamente o nome do arquivo atual e depois  de mudar apague-o

Comment: Dica que talvez explique os votos negativos: quando pedir ajuda a outras pessoas, coloque o ***mínimo de código possível*** para demonstrar seu problema. É legal ajudar os outros, mas ter que ficar lendo um monte de coisa que não tem a ver com o problema desanima muito e dá uma vontade danada de apertar -1 e ir procurar coisas mais legais pra resolver... Este guia é importante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @brasofilo Eu editei o post falando que ta resolvido já.. 5horas atras e já estava resolvido ai eu postei o código funcionando.. se alguem quiser ver o que eu alterei só click no editado ali..

Comment: Responda a pergunta com o código que resolveu seu problema

Comment: como faço para marcar quando estiver resolvido @brasofilo

Comment: Confere aqui: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/201)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$novoNome = $img;

if(isset($_POST['edit_profile_avatar']))
{
    if(!empty($_FILES['img']['name']))
    {
    // INICIO UPLOAD IMG
    //INFO IMAGEM
    $file       = $_FILES['img'];
    $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    //PASTA
    $folder     = 'upload/users/';

    //REQUISITOS
    $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
    $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 1;

    //MENSAGENS
    $msg        = array();
    $errorMsg   = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
        2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
        3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
        4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
        );

    if($numFile <= 0)
    {
        /*echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        Selecione uma imagem!
        </div>';*/
    }
    else if($numFile >=2)
    {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        Você ultrapassou o limite de upload. Selecione apenas uma foto e tente novamente!
        </div>';
    }
    else
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++)
        {
            $name   = $file['name'][$i];
            $type       = $file['type'][$i];
            $size       = $file['size'][$i];
            $error  = $file['error'][$i];
            $tmp        = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

            $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
            $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

            if($error != 0)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
            else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
            else if($size > $maxSize)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";

            else
            {

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome))
                {
                    $archive = "upload/users/" .$img;
                    unlink($archive);
                }
                else
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";
            }
            foreach($msg as $pop)
                echo '';
                //echo $pop.'<br>';
            }
        }
    } // input de img vazio
    else
    {
        $novoNome = $img;
    }

    try
    {
        $atualizarUsuario = $conexao->prepare("UPDATE users SET avatar=:img WHERE id=:id");
        $atualizarUsuario->bindParam(':id', $idUsuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $atualizarUsuario->bindParam(':img', $novoNome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $atualizarUsuario->execute();

        if($atualizarUsuario->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            echo '<script language= "JavaScript">
            location.href="/profile/'.$apelidoUsuario.'/avatar-updated";
            </script>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script language= "JavaScript">
            location.href="/profile/'.$apelidoUsuario.'/perfil-updated-error";
            </script>';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Puxa, a única diferença deste código pro da pergunta é a linha 69 que foi removida e que não faz nada... é um comentário: `//$msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Upload Realizado com Sucesso!";` . . . Yes, rodei um *diff* nos dois códigos...

Comment: Sim, removi isso, mais não foi apenas isso a alteração que fiz para funcionar tal objetivo relativo a pergunta @brasofilo

Comment: @brasofilo me surgiu uma dúvida aqui, como defino uma imagem padrão que não pode ser excluida ? Deixei uma imagem default.jpg la como padrão e quero que ela não seja excluida

Comment: uai, `if(image==default) nao-excluir()`? Eu deixaria numa outra pasta que o PHP não mexe...

Comment: @brasofilo Não entendi..

Comment: @brasofilo Resolvido = if (empty($avatarUser))  {$avatarUser = "default.jpg"; }

Answer (score 2):

Nesse caso, passe por `POST` a imagem antiga e a nova:

```
$image     = $_POST['nova'];
$image_old = $_POST['old'];

/* Faça upload da nova imagem normalmente */

$clear = unlink($image_old); // apaga imagem antiga
```

Comment: Não entendi.. Olha o código que editei o topico, já está funcionando